# work applications In standby

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, background-process

My application should be monitoring battery status and send messages via e-mail when certain battery charge 25%. However, I can not get it to work in the background because it doesn't fit the requirements to run in the background. Should the application monitor battery status if the user is multitasking? Or should the application stop so it won't run?

I am sure that can to do it because in this application it works but it is unclear how:

[Application that works](http://9to5mac.com/2013/10/05/giveaway-dataman-pro-a-powerful-easy-to-use-data-tracker-on-sale-until-tomorrow/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataman does not check data usage continuously. It checks for differences every time you open the app.
If you are not planning to make a jailbroken app, you will not be able to do what you want to do. **Your app will be suspended by iOS** unless you use one of the allowed Background Modes.
**Note**: If you declare a background mode and you don't actually use it for it's purpose, your app will be rejected.

Comment: Вы мой спаситель !!! более недели, пытаясь выяснить, что вы положили в 6 строк! Что бы вы посоветовали мне делать в моем случае? Есть идея, чтобы добавить использование карт, но в этом случае, вся программа будет работать в фоновом режиме или просто карте? and how dataman sends a notification if it is not stored in the background and can not receive data current to that moment?

Comment: I don't speak russian ;) But i think that dataman estimates usage projection and set a local notification to be triggered later.

Comment: sorry.accidentally wrote :) I can not understand , if I use  maps background,all application will work in background or only work maps(coordinate tracking) ? it is possible that an application running in the background,because use maps?

Comment: The whole app will work, but if you don't have a feature that actually use it, Apple will reject it. And don't forget that having the GPS on all the time drains the device's battery.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question.I think the use of add maps to show users details information based on its location and history it of places . can my app update data unrelated to maps in background? thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: Yes, but you will have to keep the GPS on and have a VERY good reason to keep it on, or you won't pass Apple's validation.

Comment: perhaps they approve if this is not the main function my applications?

Comment: Would you give advice on a similar question by  e-mail ?